# Is there a legal standard for Heraldry & Family Coats of Arms in U.S.?

Tags: united-states, heraldry

How can I know that a rendering of Heraldry or a Coat of Arms from a website is legit? What is the legal standard in the U.S.?

Answer (score 9):

Dick Eastman covered this in his blog a few years ago:

> The United States has never accepted the concept of nobility and
>   therefore has no officially-recognized heralds. Several American
>   organizations claim to be able to issue coats of arms but any such
>   arms issued by an American organization have to be considered as
>   "unofficial." There is no official issuing body in the U.S.

See the [full article](http://blog.eogn.com/eastmans_online_genealogy/2008/09/your-family-coa.html), which is useful background reading, especially for anybody thinking that coats of arms belong to families (they are specific to individuals, but can be inherited, subject to permission).

Comment: [US Constitution Article 1, Section 9, Clause 8](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Constitution_of_the_United_States_of_America#Section_9): "No Title of Nobility shall be granted by the United States"

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend you review the information provided by the American Heraldry Society:

https://www.americanheraldry.org/education-resources/guidelines-for-heraldic-practice/